# How to define the Einstein summation convention in Mathematica?

Tags: functions, custom-notation

How to define a  Einstein summation convention in Mathematica?

Say, how to let Mathematica know `T[i,i]` equals `T[1,1]+T[2,2]+T[3,3]`? How to define the function `T[i,j]`?

I know there are several Mathematica-abased programs that can do this, but still I want to know how to define my own.

Comment: This is partially related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/15330/1089 ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a single Function `T` this is pretty easy:

```
T[i_, i_] /; ! NumberQ[i] := Sum[T[j, j], {j, 3}]
```

A quick test gives:

```
In[7]:= T[i, i]

Out[7]= T[1, 1] + T[2, 2] + T[3, 3]
```

If you want to always sum over two equal indices for several functions, this might need some extra work though.

Comment: Thanks, einbandi. The answer is just what I want.