# Differentiation of Vector Equation

Tags: differentials

Is it possible to get symbolic derivatives of equations with vectors as arguments without specifying every vector element explicitly.

Something like

```
f[A_Vector, B_Vector] := Dot[A, B]
D[f[a, b], a[[1]]]
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do vector calculus in Mathematica?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/19596/is-it-possible-to-do-vector-calculus-in-mathematica)

Answer (score 1):

The vector elements just need to be specified symbolically. This can be done implicitly by specifying the dimension of the vectors.

```
f[a_,b_,n_]:=Dot[Table[Subscript[a, i],{i,1,n}],Table[Subscript[b, i],{i,1,n}]]
D[f[a, b, 5], Subscript[a, 1]]
```

> Subscript[b, 1]

Which looks nicer in the notebook: 
[image]

Comment: Yes, this works of course but I would like to get the result in terms of the input vectors a and b.

Comment: @paw May you add an example of the desired output for clarification.