# Curl expression does not evaluate

Tags: vector-calculus

I am using *Mathematica* 8 on OS X.

I am trying to compute the cylindrical curl of a symbolic vector following *Mathematica* documentation.

```
Needs["VectorAnalysis`"]
Curl[{f[r, θ, z]}, {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
```

But the output is exactly the same as the input.

> ```
> Curl[{f[r, θ, z]}, {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]
> ```

How do I get *Mathematica* to symbolically evaluate the curl? This is a test run for wanting to symbolically evaluate more complicated cylindrical curls and cylindrical cross products later.

Comment: You must have a 3-dimensional Vector for Curl. Read the docs please.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Curl[f[r, θ, z], {r, θ, z}, "Cylindrical"]` ? That works in V10.2

Comment: @m-goldberg you have the Curl of a Scalar, the OP wants the Curl of a 1-dimensional Vector. That is not the same. The Curl of a Scalar works in V9.0 too.

Comment: @Willinski Although you are correct, I don't think the question needs to be closed, because the pertinent version-8 syntax is hard to find.

Answer (score 6):

It could be that you just neglected to define the function `f` as a three-component vector, but even if you did, you would have gotten no result.

The documentation for `Curl` in *Mathematica* version 8 doesn't tell you how to specify the coordinates, and the documentation for version 10 is *not applicable* in version 8.

You can find the correct usage of `Curl` in the `VectorAnalysis` tutorial linked from the page for `Curl`, at the very bottom. Here is an example:

```
f = {0 , 1, 0};
Curl[f, Cylindrical[r, ϕ, z]]

(* ==> {0, 0, 1/r} *)
```

The syntax you used, `Curl[f,"Cylindrical"]`, would not work in version 8, even with `f` defined as above. This was an incompatible change in the usage of `Curl`, after it was moved from the `VectorAnalysis` to the `System` context. I think it is indeed confusing because the version-8 documentation for `Curl` was not specific enough.

Comment: I verified that your example does work - thanks. But how do I implement a generic function whose cylindrical curl (Curl f) or cross product (f x g) returns the analytic symbolic solution?

Comment: Paste `VectorAnalysis/tutorial/VectorAnalysis` into the Help browser and go to the bottom of the page. The three *cylindrical* components of the function are called `f`, `g`, and `h` there. See also [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/19707/245).