# Do a gauge transformation for a Chern-Simons theory?

Tags: functions, symbolic, algebraic-manipulation, gui-construction

Suppose we have the following Lagrangian density:

$$
L=\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}\big(\sum_a  A^a_{\mu}(x) \partial_\nu A^a_{\rho}(x)-\sum_{a,b,c}\frac{1}{3} f^{bca} A^a_{\mu}(x) A^b_{\nu}(x) A^c_{\rho}(x)\big)
$$
under this infinitesimal transformation + $\dots$
$$
A^a_\mu(x) \to {A^a_\mu}'(x)\equiv (A^a_\mu(x) +   f^{abc}  \alpha^b(x) A^c_\mu(x) +  \partial_\mu \alpha^a(x) +\dots) 
$$
where $x\equiv(t,x_1,x_2)$, $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho}$ is anti-symmetric and cyclic, $f^{abc}$ is anti-symmetric, but [may not be cyclic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/612537/lie-groups-with-structure-constant-f-abc-neq-f-bca) in general.

We end up with  $L \to L'$ under $A^a_\mu \to {A^a_\mu}'$.

And my question is:

How to obtain a **well-simplified** $L'$ using *Mathematica* ?

The key point is: **without knowing the detailed structure $f^{abc}$, but only implement $f^{abc}$'s property to simplify the answer $L'$.**

ps. I just took a glimpse at this post [-how-to-manipulate-gauge-theory-in-mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/how-to-manipulate-gauge-theory-in-mathematica), but I wonder whether there is a simpler way, since I am only doing **pure algebra?**

Comment: Care to share a code snippet ?

Comment: I don't have a code yet. I am looking for one, or writing one myself. :)

Comment: Of course, I shall say the purpose here is definitely NOT to teach me on gauge invariant: which is obvious from the perspective of a finite continuous gauge transformation: $U^\dagger (A-i d) U$ on the C-S term Tr[$A \wedge A +(2/3)A \wedge A \wedge A$]. The purpose here is to teach Mathematica how to simplify nontrivial algebra. This is what I need. :)