# How to solve fluid flow problem based on Navier-Stokes equations?

Tags: differential-equations, numerics, physics, fluid-dynamics

Does anyone know or can provide any examples how fluid flow problem can be formulated and solved in Wolfram Language? Simplest cases of 1D or 2D flows based on [Navier-Stokes equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navier-Stokes_Equations) or even their linearized version would be great to see.

Comment: What have you tried? There is a simple example in the [What's New in Mathematica 10](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/a-stokes-flow-in-a-channel.html), just plug into the Navier-Stokes instead of pure Stokes flow.

Comment: Change the equation to Indicial notation and follow http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/15307/how-to-manipulate-gauge-theory-in-mathematica/15330#15330 and http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14654/how-to-define-the-einstein-summation-convention-in-mathematica

Comment: Version 12 adds the requested functionality. [Stationary Navier-Stokes](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/navier-stokes-equation.html?product=mathematica), [Transient Navier-Stokes](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/navier-stokes-equation.html?product=mathematica), [3D Transient](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/3d-transient-fluid-flow.html?product=mathematica), [coupled Navier-Stokes and Heat](https://www.wolfram.com/language/12/nonlinear-finite-elements/energy-transport.html?product=mathematica)

Answer (score 15):

This blog is a good start:

[Using Mathematica to Simulate and Visualize Fluid Flow in a Box](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/07/09/using-mathematica-to-simulate-and-visualize-fluid-flow-in-a-box/)

It fully solves 2D problem of one moving boundary

[image]

and gets nice vertex flows:

[image]

[image]

There are detailed descriptions of proper equations and numerical discretization. You can generalize to 3D. I would look also in latest V10 functionality to see if anything can be used there to upgrade the methods of the blog - it was written before V10 came out. For instance, take a look at this [**Stokes Flow**](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/pdes-and-finite-elements/a-stokes-flow-in-a-channel.html) example which is a simplification of NS:

[image]

The same example is discussed in [Solving Partial Differential Equations with Finite Elements](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/SolvingPDEwithFEM.html) tutorial

[image]

that goes a bit further and solves for pressure and other quantities:

[image]

Comment: In routine maintenance I was preparing to delete this old closed question but I noticed your answer of general interest.  Since this question is otherwise abandoned would you please consider editing it to *specifically* fit this answer, or reposting this to a self-Q&A?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I edited the question, also added a new link and images in the answer at the end. Hope it'll do.

Comment: Did you vote to reopen?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I do not see an option for this.

Comment: I have trouble remembering the details of site mechanics; perhaps you cannot vote to reopen since you voted to close originally.  I'll just reopen directly.