# Generating an efficient way to compute einsum?

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, combinatorics

Given an einsum like below, how could I generate an efficient computation graph for it?

$$X_{ik} M_{ij}M_{kl} X_{jl}$$

The indices range from $1$ to $d$ and the goal is to minimize computation time assuming $d$ is large. IE, prefer $O(d^{k})$ to $O(d^{k+1})$. For the sum above, it can be computed as follows:

$$A_{kj}=X_{ik} M_{ij}\\B_{kj} = M_{kl} X_{jl}\\c=A_{kj}B_{kj}$$

You could specify this solution in terms of indices occurring in the expression

```
A={ik,ij}
B={kl,jl}
c={A,B}
```

More compactly, the problem and solution can be encoded as follows:

```
input: {ik, ij, kl, jl}
output: {{ik, ij}, {kl, jl}}
```

This is likely to be an NP-complete problem, but there are probably heuristics to find near-optimal solution most of the time.

**Edit**: the most important case for practical applications was when result can be expressed in terms matrices, which can be done using Carl Woll's package in the answer. Specifically, it seems to work to get efficient matrix expression for the following einsum

$$X_{ik} (M_{ij}^{(1)} M_{kl}^{(2)} + M_{ik}^{(3)} M_{jl}^{(4)} + M_{il}^{(5)} M_{jk}^{(6)}) X_{jl}$$

as

$$\text{tr}(M_2' X' M_1 X)+\text{tr}(M_3' X)\text{tr}(M_4' X)+\text{tr}(M_6' X M_5' X)$$

This was computed using the answer below as

```
PacletInstall[
    "TensorSimplify", 
    "Site" -> "http://raw.githubusercontent.com/carlwoll/TensorSimplify/master"
]

<< TensorSimplify`
einsum[in_List -> out_, arrays__] := 
  Module[{res = isum[in -> out, {arrays}]}, res /; res =!= $Failed];

isum[in_List -> out_, arrays_List] := 
 Catch@Module[{indices, contracted, uncontracted, contractions, 
    transpose}, 
   If[Length[in] != Length[arrays], 
    Message[einsum::length, Length[in], Length[arrays]];
    Throw[$Failed]];
   MapThread[
If[IntegerQ@TensorRank[#1] && Length[#1] != TensorRank[#2], 
  Message[einsum::shape, #1, #2];
  Throw[$Failed]] &, {in, arrays}];
   indices = Tally[Flatten[in, 1]];
   If[DeleteCases[indices, {_, 1 | 2}] =!= {}, 
    Message[einsum::repeat, 
     Cases[indices, {x_, Except[1 | 2]} :> x]];
    Throw[$Failed]];
   uncontracted = Cases[indices, {x_, 1} :> x];
   If[Sort[uncontracted] =!= Sort[out], 
Message[einsum::output, uncontracted, out];
Throw[$Failed]];
   contracted = Cases[indices, {x_, 2} :> x];
   contractions = Flatten[Position[Flatten[in, 1], #]] & /@ contracted;
   transpose = FindPermutation[uncontracted, out];
   Activate@
    TensorTranspose[
     TensorContract[Inactive[TensorProduct] @@ arrays, contractions], 
     transpose]]

einsum::length = 
  "Number of index specifications (`1`) does not match the number of \
arrays (`2`)";
einsum::shape = 
  "Index specification `1` does not match the array depth of `2`";
einsum::repeat = 
  "Index specifications `1` are repeated more than twice";
einsum::output = 
  "The uncontracted indices don't match the desired output";

$Assumptions = (X | M | M1 | M2 | M3 | M4 | M5 | M6) \[Element] 
   Matrices[{d, d}];
FromTensor@einsum[{{1, 3}, {1, 2}, {3, 4}, {2, 4}} -> {}, X, M1, M2, X]
FromTensor@
 TensorReduce@
  einsum[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}} -> {}, M3, M4, X, X]
FromTensor@
 TensorReduce@
  einsum[{{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}} -> {}, M5, M6, X, X]
```

Comment: I think your notations do not generalize well for larger number of indices. It seems the input can be encoded as `{{1,3},{1,2},{3,4},{2,4}}` and the output as `{{{1,3},{1,2}},{{3,4},{2,4}}}` allowing further generalizations for an arbitrary number of indices.

Comment: I think your example in Mathematica would be represented as `Tr[Transpose[M].Transpose[X].M.X]`, and I think evaluating this as normal would have the desired complexity. If so, would having a way to convert such `einsum` specs to the above `Tr` + `Dot` representation be useful?

Comment: When each building block possesses only 2 indices the problem reduces to the well known question of finding a path that traverses all points of a graph visiting each point only one time. See `FindHamiltonianPath`

Comment: @CarlWoll yes it would be useful. The motivating example was to compute Xij Mijkl Xkl where Mijkl is written as (Mij Mkl + Mik Mjl + Mil Mjk) (this is Isserlis theorem), and I think it can be done in terms of Tr and Dot operators on rank-2 tensors

Comment: @yarchik I don't see the Hamiltonian Path connection. For 2-index case, the problem reduces to finding triangulation of the graph that minimizes the size of largest maximal clique. Agree that using 1,2,3 is more convenient than "i","j","k"

Comment: The connection is as follows: map Zweibein blocks onto the vertices of a graph. Let 2 vertices be connected if the respective blocks have a common index (Einstein summation). Hamiltonian path then sets the order of the blocks' multiplication. The starting point is irrelevant because of the cyclic shift invariance under the trace. QED

Comment: @yarchik this doesn't work for $n^2$ terms arranged in a square grid, the cost of computing the sum is $d^n$

Comment: Of course it doesn't work. It is not a 2-index case anymore. Why don't you add this  as a possible example so that one does not need to guess. At the moment your formulation leaves a lot of space for misinterpretations.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "two index case". In my grid example, every term only has two indices, so the simplest grid graph is {0,1},{1,2},{2,3},{3,0}. My point was that for larger grid graphs (with two indices per term), the Hamiltonian path doesn't help

Comment: BTW, one way to see the difficulty is to try to count the number of independent sets in a grid graph. You can express "this is an independent set" as a product of 2 index terms, but computing the sum is not straightforward

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe the following will be useful for you.

You can combine my `FromTensor` function (part of my [`TensorSimplify`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/155476/45431) paclet) with my [`einsum`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/158248/45431) function to convert your `einsum` representation into [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr) + [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot).

```
$Assumptions = (X|M) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}];

FromTensor @ einsum[{{1,3}, {1,2}, {3,4}, {2,4}}->{}, X, M, M, X]
```

> Tr[Transpose[M].Transpose[X].M.X]

Hopefully the loading instructions for these functions is clear from the above links. If not, I can add them here again.

**Addendum**

If your tensor has disconnected pieces, then `FromTensor` doesn't currently work. A simple fix is to include [`TensorReduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorReduce). From the comments in the examples (I think I fixed a typo in the second example):

```
$Assumptions = (X | M) ∈ Matrices[{d,d}];

FromTensor @ TensorReduce @ einsum[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}} -> {2, 4}, M, M, X]
FromTensor @ TensorReduce @ einsum[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {2, 4}} -> {}, M, M, X, X]
```

> M Tr[Transpose[M].X]
>
> Tr[Transpose[M].X]^2

Comment: Hm I'm wondering if it could be made to work with `X, M1, M2, X`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Something like `$Assumptions = (X | M1 | M2) ∈ Matrices[{d, d}]; FromTensor@einsum[{{1,3},{1,2},{3,4},{2,4}}->{},X,M1,M2,X]`?

Comment: Oh nice! I was able to check most of my derivations. This result of this one could be simpler `FromTensor@einsum[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}} -> {2, 4}, M, M, X]` , I expected to see `tr(M'X)M`. Also couldn't related quantity `FromTensor@einsum[{{1, 3}, {2, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}} -> {}, M, M, X, X]`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Right, FromTensor (currently) doesn't work with tensors that have disconnected pieces. I'm planning to add support for that soon. In the meantime, you could use `FromTensor @ TensorReduce @ ...` instead.

Comment: Aha, that works! I think this should be part of standard Mathematica functionality, it could've saved me quite a bit of time