# Implementing Tensors

Tags: tensors

Please see the below question. This is what I need to implement in Mathematica.

[image: Ques]

Comment: This doesn't directly answer the question, but I found Carl Woll's tensor package useful for tensor computation, for example here -- https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207336/generating-an-efficient-way-to-compute-einsum

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does it answer your question?

```
f={{l x[1],0},{0,l(x[1]+x[2])}};
g[μ_]:=Sum[f[[μ,κ]]D[f[[ν,κ]],x[ν]],{ν,2},{κ,2}]
g[1]
Out[1]= l^2 x[1]
```

Comment: Exactly. This is what I want.