# Einstein Summation convention in mathematica

Tags: summation

```
$Assumptions = 
 x \[Element] Matrices[{2*M, 2*M}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]]

x[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} x @@ Sort@{arg} 
Format[x[arg__]] := Subscript[x, arg]

p[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} p @@ Sort@{arg}
p[___, j_, j_, ___] = 0;

Format[p[arg__]] := Subscript[p, arg]
test1 = (4 *p[4, i, k, l] *x[2, i] *x[k, 2] *x[l, 3]) + (4* 
    p[1, j, k, l] *x[2, j]* x[k, 2]* x[l, 2]) + (p[1, 2, 3, i]* 
    x[1, i])
```

I want to implement the above in such a way that repeated indices only summed up just as in Einstein summation convention. Any way to do this?
When I perform summation as:

```
Sum[test1, {i, 4}] // Expand
```

I am getting:

```
Subscript[p, 1, 2, 3, 4] Subscript[x, 1, 4] + 
 16 Subscript[p, 1, j, k, l] Subscript[x, 2, j] Subscript[x, 2, k]
   Subscript[x, 2, l] + 
 4 Subscript[p, 1, 4, k, l] Subscript[x, 1, 2] Subscript[x, 2, k]
   Subscript[x, 3, l] - 
 4 Subscript[p, 3, 4, k, l] Subscript[x, 2, 3] Subscript[x, 2, k]
   Subscript[x, 3, l]
```

But I want to use Einstein summation convention in which only repeated indices sums up. Is there a way that Mathematica to perform summation only for repeated indices only,not for constants.

Comment: good question! minor typo: capital `I` in the last term of `test1` (which I'm guessing should be lowercase?)

Comment: @thorimur its lower case

Comment: @Jasmine Please see this    https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14654/how-to-define-the-einstein-summation-convention-in-mathematica

Comment: @qahtah It's applicable only for single variable

Comment: @Jasmine Have a look at this package  https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2561

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are admittedly probably better off using a package such as the one @qahtah mentioned in the comments or the package [xAct](http://www.xact.es/), but just for fun, here is a way of defining a function `EinsteinSum` which does what you're looking for—unless I've misunderstood. If you have any questions about why this works the way it does, or if I've misunderstood what you're looking for, let me know! :)

```
Clear[EinsteinSum]

EinsteinSum[Times[a___, (p_Symbol)[x___, i_Symbol, y___], b___, (q_Symbol)[w___, i_Symbol, z___], c___]] := 
 EinsteinSum[
  a b c With[{ii = Unique["ii"]}, Sum[p[x, ii, y] q[w, ii, z], {ii, 4}]]]

EinsteinSum[Times[a_, b__]] := EinsteinSum[Expand[a b]] /; ! SameQ[a b, Expand[a b]]

EinsteinSum[Plus[a_, b__]] := Plus @@ (EinsteinSum /@ {a, b})

EinsteinSum[x_] := x
```

Test:

```
test1 = (4 *p[4, i, k, l] *x[2, i] *x[k, 2] *x[l, 3]) + (4* 
    p[1, j, k, l] *x[2, j]* x[k, 2]* x[l, 2]) + (p[1, 2, 3, i]* 
    x[1, i])

EinsteinSum[test1]

(* Output: a huge expanded form *)
```

Comment: There is a small issue. In my case   $Assumptions = 
 x \[Element] Matrices[{2*M, 2*M}, Reals, Antisymmetric[{1, 2}]];      x[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} x @@ Sort@{arg} 
Format[x[arg__]] := Subscript[x, arg];    p[arg__] /; ! OrderedQ@{arg} := Signature@{arg} p @@ Sort@{arg}
p[___, j_, j_, ___] = 0;
Format[p[arg__]] := Subscript[p, arg]       So I define them as                                test1 = (4 *p[4, i, k, l] *x[2, i] *x[k, 2] *x[l, 3]) + (4* 
    p[1, j, k, l] *x[2, j]* x[k, 2]* x[l, 2]) + (p[1, 2, 3, i]* 
    x[1, I])        So your code is not working!

Comment: Your code is great. But can you please let me know how it works in this case

Comment: I have edited my question

Comment: @Jasmine ahhh, I see! I've edited my answer, but I still think it falls a bit short because it doesn't take dimensions into account. let me see.

Comment: It's working perfectly for 4 case. Great code

Comment: @Jasmine glad it helps! :) I think we might be able to leverage `TensorContract` and mathematica's usage of `$Assumptions` to make it a bit more general. if I have time I'd like to come back and improve it tomorrow!

Comment: That's great. Mainly it would be of great help if we can sum only desired indices at a time. For example at first if I want to sum repeated 'i'  only that would be great. Also what about a summation with restriction. ie, summing indices with restriction. eg: How to implement i<j summations.